# Inkscape and Flowcharts: Opacity, color mixing and bounding box

Tags: inkscape

I do want to create a flowchart similar to this one. Colors have an alpha value of 255 and I set the opacity lower for decreasing color saturation. The arrow is drawn on a second layer. I do face two problems. First, I would like to hide the arrow behind the boxes (no color mixing). Second, the arrow (intersection of a rectangle with a triangle) has a bounding box which is much larger than the object itself. How can I fix this ?

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to the comments I realized that I mixed up the alpha and saturation values. I do no know what happened with the box. I did redraw the arrow and now it is normal again. I guess it happend while scaling it (using the mouse)

Comment: If you don't want color mixing, then don't use opacity or alpha. Keep them both at 100%, and then use the light / saturation / hue controls to adjust color.

Comment: Only ask one question at a time. For two, independently answerable questions, it should be possible to answer one and have the other one open.

Answer (score -1):

To hide the arrow behind the boxes (no color mixing):

- copy the boxes
- make them 100% white, no transparency
- put the white boxes below the tranparent/colored boxes but above the arrow.

And only ask one question at a time, so pull your second question out and make it a independent one.